# Can you add Mailto links in css style tags

Tags: html, css, mailto

Can one add mailto (any anchor link) into your style tag?
The reason I'm asking is, I have some styling elements that is not working with my email anchor link in my html body tag, so I was wondering, if I can just add it to my CSS instead, to try see if that will work, can that be done?

If so, what tags do i use?

If this is my example:

```
<a><h1 id="emailLink" style="color:red">Email us here</h1></a>
```

Comment: Can you give an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what's not working for you? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: the mailto link that would be:href:mailto:email@address.com, can one add that email link, in the CSS tag, or does it have to be in the body tag only?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `a` tag and style it as such: `a[href^="mailto:"]{color: red;}` or `a[href^="mailto:"]{color: inherit;}`. The `^=` is special css comparison to target element which `href` property starts with- in this case- `mailto:`.

Comment: thank you, but cani put the actual address of the email in the css?a[href^="mailto:"]{color: inherit;} where would the actual email fit in?

Comment: Like this: `a[href="mailto:email@localhost"]{color: inherit;}`

Answer (score -1):

If your question is whether you can define `mailto` as a CSS property, then the answer is **no**. `mailto` is a link prefix, signaling the browser that the following string is an e-mail address, and should be handled as such. For example:

```
<a href="mailto:person@example.com">Send e-mail</a>
```

On the other hand, this isn't valid, because `mailto` isn't a known CSS property:

```
<a style="mailto:person@example.com">Send e-mail</a>
```

Comment: You are totally wrong :) Why do you need prefix in inline styles when you are styling EXACTLY element with `style`, why then would someone want to target something there? And besides: Answer is yes.

Comment: @MaciejKwas I'm sorry, but you are not making any sense. Please try and rephrase that. Since the question isn't really clear, I have answered what I believe the original poster intended to ask. To that question, my answer is correct: you can not specify the recipient's e-mail address within CSS.

Comment: yes, I must admit that level of question is below zero, no doubts.

Comment: How is my question level below zero? I asked if you can add an email link (the actual email) to the css div tag...and not in the HTML as per usual? Any case, ill figure it out, thank you